# Create a network from node and edge csv files using cytoscape

Tags: graph, cytoscape

getting these network [files](https://www.kaggle.com/andreagarritano/wikipedia-article-networks) from kaggle, I want to create a network. Using Gephi, it is quit simple. However, on Cytoscape, I create an empty network and I try to import edge and nodes files by drag and drop or import bottom but nothing is added! Anyone tried this before ?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty easy in Cytoscape, also -- just a bit different.  In Cytoscape, you start by creating your network, not as an empty network but by importing your edge file.  Use **File->Import->Network from file** and just tell Cytoscape which column has your source node and which column has your target node (in the example, there are only two columns, so it's pretty easy).  Then you can import information about your nodes using **File->Import->Table from file** and choose the column that has the node id as your key column.

-- scooter